# How to map in XML List<Entity> field with hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, list

I googled all day and I cant find one good example how to map this kind of objects:

```
class Parent{
    private Integer parentId;
    private String parentName;
    private List<Child> childs;

    // ....... getters and setters ............
}

class Child{
    private Integer childId;
    private String childName;

    private Parent parent;

    // ....... getters and setters ...........
}
```

I have no idea how to make map for this kind of List.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate documentation has plenty of [examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html), including [this one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-bidir) which is basically what you're looking for. XML mapping would for your case would look like:

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent">
  <id name="parentId" column="id" type="integer" /> <!-- TODO: specify generator -->
  <property name="parentName" type="string" column="name" />
  <bag name="childs" table="Children" inverse="true">
    <key column="parent_id" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="Children">
  <id name="childId" column="id" type="integer" /> <!-- TODO: specify generator -->
  <property name="childName" type="string" column="name" />
  <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

For examples of annotation-based mapping take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections)

Comment: Doesn't that map the List as a mere Collection (i.e. not keeping the order of the List intact)?

Comment: It's mapped as bag - keeping list semantics, but not maintaining order. If order is important (OP didn't mention that), `<bag>` can be replaced with `<list>` but you'll need another column in the `Children` table to maintain element indexes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare your `List<Child>` as `IList<Child>`, because NHibernate needs to be able to use its own collection-type that implements IList.

In your mapping, you should use the 'bag' element to map your List.  (Are you sure you want to use a List and not a Set ?  Since a List allows that one single entity occurs more then once in the list, whereas a Set does not allow that).

This is how I should do it:

```
public class Parent
{
   private IList<Child> _children = new List<Child>();

   public ReadOnlyCollection<Child> Children
   {
       get {return _children.AsReadOnly();}
   }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent">
    <list name="Children" table="..." access="field.camelcase-underscore" inverse="true">
        <key column="..." />
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </list>
</class>
```

(Ommitted al the other properties for brevity)

(Ow, now that I see it, you're using Hibernate ?  My code example is in C#, so I do not know whether you have the notion of ReadOnlyCollection etc...)

Comment: Since the question is tagged "hibernate" I assume he is using Java and not C#, so "List<Child>" is correct (in Java List is the interface, the implementations are ArrayList, LinkedList, ...).